# Loading image in JavaFX causes AccessControlException when deployed as jnlp

Tags: java, jnlp, javafx-8, accesscontrolexception

I have a very simple JavaFX application. It needs to draw an image I keep as a png in the "resources" directory.
I initialize it like this:

```
private final static Image customerImage;
static {
    Path imageLink = Paths.get("resources", "homeIcon.png");
    customerImage = new Image("file:"+imageLink.toString(),true);
}
```

This works fine when I run it straight from my IDE.

But when I deploy the application as a JavaFX package and run the resulting jnlp then the Image constructor throws an AccessControlException, specifically:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
```

Which, if I understand correctly, means it doesn't have access to search for the file. How should I resolve this? It also seems strange that it would look in a directory when deployed as .jnpl, should I place the .png file somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
customerImage = new Image("file:"+imageLink.toString(),true);
```

That is probably not forming an URL.
  It should be:

```
customerImage = new Image(imageLink.toURI().toURL().toString(),true);
```

Comment: the problem with this is that I need to deal with URL malformation exception which is a pain in a static initialization.
JavaFX guide says to use class-loader's getResourceAsStream() which is a bit less annoying